# Why don't Xamarin.Forms CollectionView SelectedItems remain highlighted after SearchBar query when using SQLite table as ItemSource?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, collectionview, selecteditem

I have been struggling to make my inventory lists maintain consistent highlighted items when using a SearchBar or sometimes navigating away from the page. I see this great looking sample from the MS Docs' "Xamarin.Forms CollectionView Selection : Multiple Pre-Selection"

And I took this SearchBar sample:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-searchbardemos/

And I have modified the Xaml w/MVVM page to look more like my project: https://github.com/BullCityCabinets/MyXFMultiSelectExample-2001005

The frustrating thing is... the modified sample works!  I gather from @Jason that I am completely replacing the view's ItemSource, and the binding don't know how to identify the new instances of the object. To compare:

The MS Docs Sample data source is a public static ObservableCollection

```
public static class DataService
{
    public static ObservableCollection<string> Fruits { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>
    { "Akee", "Apple", etc...
```

and uses this call when a search is made:

```
public static ObservableCollection<string> GetSearchResults(string queryString)
    {
        var normalizedQuery = queryString?.ToLower() ?? "";
        var myList = Fruits.Where(f => f.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(normalizedQuery)).ToList();
        
        var myOC = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        foreach (var f in myList)
        { myOC.Add(f); }
        return myOC;
    }
```

My data source is a single SQLite table of about 350 objects, and on searching I call this:

```
public Task<List<MyInventoryClass>> GetInventoryByQuery(string query)
    {
        return Db.Table<MyInventoryClass>()                
            .Where(i => 
            i.Name1.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower()) == true)
            .ToListAsync();            
    }
```

There is an auto-incrementing Id property on the objects, so I have something to search for... I'm just not sure how to re-establish the link between SelectedItems and the new list.

Should I be making a new call to the SQLite table every time there is a search?

Should I, instead, save all 350 items in a static property at startup, then display queries from that?  What if there were 3,500 objects, surely that's not the best solution, is it?

How and where do you insert a foreach to join the existing SelectedItems list to the freshly queried CollectionView ItemSource?  The objects in the SelectedItems list have unique Id properties, so there is something identify the items with, aside from index numbers (seen in the MS Docs Pre-Selection Sample).

Comment: I download the project from the link you provided. The project of Mokeys works well with `SelectedItems`. Have you do somechanges with the sample code? Could you provide this for me with screenshot?

Comment: I will post a sample project today!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to remove the highlight from a CollectionView after selection, always add this to the page if you use a `GridItemsLayout`

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonState">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter
                                Property="BackgroundColor"
                                Value="White" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was going for "Remain Highlighted" not "Remove Highlighting."